# Add refund amount to WooCommerce refund email?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is there a way to dynamically load the refund amount (i.e., $50) in the WooCommerce email template? I've searched all over to see if this was something that could be pulled from the order details and have come up empty.

Comment: If you issue a refund through WooCommerce, the email lists the amount of the refund.  If you're having issues writing code to modify the default functionality of WooCommerce, then *post your code* and we can help you try to debug it.

Answer (score 1):

The refund amount is listed in the standard refund email.

See this example:

[image: screenshot of refund email showing partial refund]

The contents of this email are defined in the template at

wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails/customer-refunded-order.php

If you want to change this template, copy the template into a directory within your theme named /woocommerce keeping the same file structure but removing the /templates/ subdirectory.

Example: To override the admin order notification, copy:

wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails/customer-refunded-order.php

to

wp-content/themes/yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/customer-refunded-order.php

YourTheme can be either a parent theme or your child theme.

The copied file will now override the WooCommerce default template file.

Warning: Do not edit these files within the core plugin itself as they are overwritten during the upgrade process and any customizations will be lost.

More information & source of some of this text:

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/